# Why doesn't my RecyclerView show up when it's nested inside NestedScrollView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement a recycler view with a collapsing toolbar layout. I have followed [this tutorial](http://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/), but so far my RecyclerView does not show up. All the other views are visible, though.

Here's my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/listing_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_post" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/errorView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/listing_loading_error"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:text="Error" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loadingView"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The progress bar and the error textview do show up when I toggle them from the code, but the recycler view won't show up.

Comment: From my experience you do not actually need a `NestedScrollView`, any layout with the `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` will do. Try changing the `NestedScrollView` to a `FrameLayout`, and place your `RecyclerView`, `TextView` and `ProgressBar` in the `FrameLayout`.

Comment: Try to use `setMinimumHeight` for the `RecyclerView` if it is within a `NestedScrollView` or it will be 0.

Answer (score 0):

set recyclerview to actual dp height. It worked for me.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/listing_recycler_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/item_post" />
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I'd rather have it "full-size" anyway.